# Is an "Electric" YASnippet possible?

Tags: yasnippet

I want to emulate (and even replace) some electric modes (eg. `cperl-electric`, `ruby-electric`) with my own custom templates using `yasnippet`, but it doesn't seem to be possible - can someone enlighten me?

So in addition to normal templates triggered by <kbd>TAB</kbd>, I'd like to have some snippets triggered simply by a space, eg. typing "for<kbd>SPACE</kbd>" should fire a snippet instead of having to type "for<kbd>TAB</kbd>".

Is that possible?

**Update**: I also realise that for some "electric" features I want some patterns to fire without any sort of trigger key - eg. like cperl-mode turns { into a paired {} with the insertion point in the middle, I'd like to do the same for single and double quotes. (Of course in this case what I really want is `paren-mode` to work with syntax less regular than lisp, but I fought that battle some years ago with only limited success!)

Comment: You might want to check out the built-in [`abbrev-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Abbrevs.html#Abbrevs).

Comment: Thanks @Dan, I hadn't really looked at `abbrev-mode` before. It's a bit confusing! I also realised that to properly do "electric" things I need some patterns to fire without a space, eg. turning a ' into a paired '' with the insertion point in the middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change yasnippet's trigger key to <kbd>SPC</kbd>, but it's not per snippet.

```el
(define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "<tab>") nil)
(define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "TAB") nil)
(define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "SPC") ; `yas-maybe-expand' new in 0.12
  (or (bound-and-true-p yas-maybe-expand) #'yas-expand))
```

See [trigger key](http://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-expansion.html#sec-1-1).

---

> what I really want is paren-mode to work with syntax less regular than lisp, but I fought that battle some years ago with only limited success!)

You can try to emulate this with keybinding snippets, see [`# binding:` direct keybinding](http://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html#sec-2-6) and [joaotavora/yasnippet#533](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/pull/533).

e.g. this would give you electric parens:

```
# -*- mode: snippet; require-final-newline: nil -*-
# name: (
# binding: (
# --
($0)
```

But it's probably better to use something like [`smartparens`](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens), or `electric-pair-mode` as joaotavora suggested:

> If you want to try out a parenthesis and quote matching alternative to
>   `smartparens`, I suggest, in this order:
>
> - `electric-pair-mode` built-in emacs 24.4
> - `autopair-mode` available at http://github.com/joaotavora/autopair

Comment: Oh awesome, a few great options here. Hooray for emacs.stackechange!